# OS X 10.9.3 Terminal bash find causing programs to run?

Tags: bash, shell, osx-mavericks

I ran this command in Terminal, using Bash as my shell on OS X 10.9.3:

sudo find / -type f -ls | grep -i 'asrv-a.akamaihd.net' > stuff.txt

I expected only lines in files containing that string to show up in stuff.txt. Instead, various processes like yes, app store, audacity, vim, calculator, automater, and who knows what have been triggered.

How did this happen? Do I need to fix things?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "triggered"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command,

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -i 'asrv-a.akamaihd.net' {} \; > stuff.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

'xargs' is missing after the pipe. The posix program [`xargs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) reads space separated words from stdin and uses them as arguments.

But you probably want to use recursive grep: `grep -Ri 'asrv-a.akamaihd.net' /`. The argument `-I` (ignore binary fields) might come in handy, too.